# localdate parsing can't parse hours and minutes

Tags: java, date, java-time, date-parsing, localdate

I need to get the date from a `String`, the format is the following: `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm`

The input has that format and I want the same format for my dates (year-month-day hour:minutes). When I did this:

```
LocalDate aux = LocalDate.parse(times.get(index),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm "));
```

with this input: `2017-12-05 20:16`
I get only this: `2017-12-05`

I don't know why, I've tried a lot of formats and always lost the hours and minutes. Any idea?

Comment: What do you think a `LocalDate` represents?

Comment: As the name suggests LocalDate just stores year, month and day . LocalDateTime is the one to go for if you want both date and time.

Comment: Also, remove the trailing space at the end of the pattern.

Comment: It is a strength, though also a little bit of an obstacle, that there are several modern Java date and time classes. You need to make a little effort to pick the right one for your purpose. Once you’ve done that, you have a classes that is (usually) exactly fitted for that purpose rather than the old supposed-to-fit-all `Date` class. @PallaviSonal is correct about which class you need in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`LocalDate` only has year, month, day fields. It cannot contain time of day data.

Use `LocalDateTime` instead.

```
LocalDateTime aux = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-12-05 20:16", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm"));
```

Comment: now , between date and time i get a 'T' is posible to remove? @bowmore

Comment: @Aikas The string with T is the result of `toString` method. If you want a different format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: That's the default formatting you get when printing a `LocalDateTime`, use `DateTimeFormatter` to print it in the format you want.

Comment: @Andreas the T is not needed in the `DateTimeFormatter` used for parsing. In fact it will make parsing fail, as the source Strings don't have a 'T'.